# how can we get the current url via JSOM on masterpage?

Tags: client-object-model

We have masterpage which is set programatically to all sites on all site collections.

On masterpage we want to redirect user based on a value to a page in layouts folder.

I have read that the layout folder is common to all users. So of I hardcode a particular url/layouts/filepath then it might throw access denied error based on user permission.

So I want to get the current site url then I will appends /layouts/filepath to this url.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(pageName) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659418%28v=office.14%29.aspx) from SharePoint JavaScript Library to return the URL to the page in the `_layouts` folder relative to the root of the website.

Example:

```
var pageUrl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("Settings.aspx");
```

Comment: i tried using this in alert box but the box didnt comeup

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve info about the current page from the object `_spPageContextInfo` injected in every page by SharePoint.

The current site(web) relative url is:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl
```

There are other interesting properties, just fire open your browser developer toolbar console to find out more.

Comment: I have nasterpage that is common to all sites and all site collections. In that there is a link to policypage hrdcoded.

Comment: So I want to make that link dynamic prefixing it with current site url so it never give error of access denied to users